# How to get rate limiting and throttling events of an application that is calling an external service at runtime?

Tags: java, multithreading, rabbitmq, throttling, rate-limiting

I am building a Java application that will poll messages from a RabbitMQ and this can be used by other applications as library for polling the messages from a single queue at a time but there is a constraint that these applications will call external services for getting the relevant data for processing and there might be rate limiting and throttling events (due to breaching of dependency TPS limits) that can take place and I need to consider that to change the rate of polling(Increase or decrease).
So how can I get those events values at runtime(lets say after a fixed interval of time) in the application that I am building?

Applications(Using the Application I am building) -------> (Calls) External Service

```
                                       <------- (Sends) Throttling/rate limiting 
                                                        events to applications that
                                                         are calling them.
```

The throttling and rate limiting events will reach the Applications(that is going to use the application that I am building) but how can my application access them at runtime?

Comment: You will need to record the usage along the way for each client application and then analysis on the fly if the limits are being reached.

Comment: @LarsNielsen Could you please elaborate how can I do that?